# jQuery Globalize parse negative number

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-globalize

I'm having problems parsing negative numbers with jQuery Globalize 1.1.1:

```
Globalize.parseNumber('-1'); // = 1
Globalize.parseNumber('-100,00'); // = 100
```

So it seems Globalize is converting the negative number to a positive number. The following CLDR-data is loaded:

- supplemental/likelySubtags
- supplemental/timeData
- supplemental/weekData
- supplemental/numberingSystems
- main/sv/numbers
- main/sv/timeZoneNames
- main/sv/ca-gregorian

Failed to find anything on this via Google-searching. Am I missing something?

Comment: The easiest way to deal with it is use the `Number` constructor directly. eg `Number('-100.00')` The default behavior with any built in constructor is to return a primitive of the same type.

Comment: The number contructor doesn't seems to work with local number formats: Number('-100,00') returns NaN

Comment: sorry missed the comma separator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Globalize (1.1.x) deduces the minus sign symbol from CLDR when parsing. In Swedish (sv), the minus sign is `−` (0x2212) not - (0x2D) as you have used in your example above. That's why it doesn't work for you. A quick test to assert parsing for negative numbers is:

```
var sv = Globalize("sv");
sv.parseNumber(sv.formatNumber(-100)) === -100; // > true
```

Having said that, it seems like "Loose Matching" is a feature that might be of your interest. It would normalize the different types of dashes, no-break space to space, comma used as abbreviation, etc before parsing. It's not supported by Globalize. We track such feature here:

https://github.com/jquery/globalize/issues/292